# Perlin noise function broken in vertex shader but not in fragment shader?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, webgl2

I am rendering a plane made of many triangles in WebGL 2 using Three.js, and I want to offset the vertices in the plane according to a Perlin noise function. However, my noise function seems to work in the fragment shader, but not in the vertex shader.

**vertex shader:**

```c
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

vec2 rand2d (vec2 uv_0) {
    return vec2(
    fract(sin(dot(uv_0, vec2(9832., -8933.2))) * 1938.4), fract(cos(dot(uv_0, vec2(-5294.2, 1243.2))) * 9043.)) * 2. - 1.;
}
float perlin_noise (vec2 uv_1) {
    vec2 v00 = floor(uv_1);
    vec2 v10 = v00 + vec2(1., 0.), v01 = v00 + vec2(0., 1.), v11 = v00 + vec2(1., 1.);
    vec2 vxy = fract(uv_1);
    float i00 = dot(rand2d(v00), vxy), i01 = dot(rand2d(v01), vxy - vec2(0., 1.)), i10 = dot(rand2d(v10), vxy - vec2(1., 0.)), i11 = dot(rand2d(v11), vxy - vec2(1., 1.));
    vec2 s = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, vxy);
    return mix(mix(i00, i10, s.x), mix(i01, i11, s.x), s.y);
}
// supplied by three
in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

// supplied by me

uniform float spacing;
uniform vec2 offset;
uniform vec2 size;
out vec3 offsetPosition;
void main() {
    // vec3 offsetPosition = position;
    offsetPosition = position + vec3(offset.x, 0, offset.y);
    offsetPosition.z = floor((cameraPosition.z + offsetPosition.z) / spacing) * spacing;
    offsetPosition.y = perlin_noise(offsetPosition.xz / 10.) * 10.;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(offsetPosition, 1.0);
}
```

**fragment shader:**

```c
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

vec2 rand2d (vec2 uv_0) {
    return vec2(
    fract(sin(dot(uv_0, vec2(9832., -8933.2))) * 1938.4), fract(cos(dot(uv_0, vec2(-5294.2, 1243.2))) * 9043.)) * 2. - 1.;
}
float perlin_noise (vec2 uv_1) {
    vec2 v00 = floor(uv_1);
    vec2 v10 = v00 + vec2(1., 0.), v01 = v00 + vec2(0., 1.), v11 = v00 + vec2(1., 1.);
    vec2 vxy = fract(uv_1);
    float i00 = dot(rand2d(v00), vxy), i01 = dot(rand2d(v01), vxy - vec2(0., 1.)), i10 = dot(rand2d(v10), vxy - vec2(1., 0.)), i11 = dot(rand2d(v11), vxy - vec2(1., 1.));
    vec2 s = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, vxy);
    return mix(mix(i00, i10, s.x), mix(i01, i11, s.x), s.y);
}
in vec3 offsetPosition;
out highp vec4 fragColor;
void main() {
    float value = perlin_noise(offsetPosition.xz / 10.) * .5 + .5;
    fragColor = vec4(value, offsetPosition.y, 0., 1.);
}
```

**result:**

[image]

The plane is completely flat (there are lots of triangles in that image, I swear), and appears red instead of yellow/green, which suggests that `offsetPosition.y` is being set to zero, which means that my Perlin noise function, which is identical in the vertex shader and the fragment shader, is returning 0 in the vertex shader only. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that you've to less triangles, respectively vertices. The vertices of your grid are distributed in that way, that the result of `offsetPosition.xz / 10.0` are integral coordinates (no fractional component). The perlin noise is a periodic function with period length of 1.0. So for all integral coordinates, the result is same.

Change to

```c
offsetPosition.y = perlin_noise(offsetPosition.xz / 100.0) * 10.0;
```

and you will get different heights for the vertices.

In general the algorithm works fine. See the example where I've used a 100x100 grid with 100x100 tiles. So `offsetPosition.xz / 10.0` generates coordinates with steps of tenth:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    let canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    let context = canvas.getContext( 'webgl2', { alpha: false } );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, context: context, antialias: true, alpha: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 10, -40);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();
  }

  function createModel() {

    var uniforms = {
          spacing : {type:'f', value: 0.0001}
    };
        
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 100);
    geometry.rotateX(Math.PI/2.0);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 1.0;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

vec2 rand2d (vec2 uv_0) {
    return vec2(
    fract(sin(dot(uv_0, vec2(9832., -8933.2))) * 1938.4), fract(cos(dot(uv_0, vec2(-5294.2, 1243.2))) * 9043.)) * 2. - 1.;
}
float perlin_noise (vec2 uv_1) {
    vec2 v00 = floor(uv_1);
    vec2 v10 = v00 + vec2(1., 0.), v01 = v00 + vec2(0., 1.), v11 = v00 + vec2(1., 1.);
    vec2 vxy = fract(uv_1);
    float i00 = dot(rand2d(v00), vxy), i01 = dot(rand2d(v01), vxy - vec2(0., 1.)), i10 = dot(rand2d(v10), vxy - vec2(1., 0.)), i11 = dot(rand2d(v11), vxy - vec2(1., 1.));
    vec2 s = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, vxy);
    return mix(mix(i00, i10, s.x), mix(i01, i11, s.x), s.y);
}

// supplied by me

uniform float spacing;
uniform vec2 offset;
uniform vec2 size;
out vec3 offsetPosition;
void main() {
    offsetPosition = position + vec3(offset.x, 0, offset.y);
    offsetPosition.y = perlin_noise(offsetPosition.xz / 10.0) * 10.0;
    offsetPosition.z = floor(offsetPosition.z / spacing) * spacing;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(offsetPosition, 1.0);
}
</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

vec2 rand2d (vec2 uv_0) {
    return vec2(
    fract(sin(dot(uv_0, vec2(9832., -8933.2))) * 1938.4), fract(cos(dot(uv_0, vec2(-5294.2, 1243.2))) * 9043.)) * 2. - 1.;
}
float perlin_noise (vec2 uv_1) {
    vec2 v00 = floor(uv_1);
    vec2 v10 = v00 + vec2(1., 0.), v01 = v00 + vec2(0., 1.), v11 = v00 + vec2(1., 1.);
    vec2 vxy = fract(uv_1);
    float i00 = dot(rand2d(v00), vxy), i01 = dot(rand2d(v01), vxy - vec2(0., 1.)), i10 = dot(rand2d(v10), vxy - vec2(1., 0.)), i11 = dot(rand2d(v11), vxy - vec2(1., 1.));
    vec2 s = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, vxy);
    return mix(mix(i00, i10, s.x), mix(i01, i11, s.x), s.y);
}
in vec3 offsetPosition;
out highp vec4 fragColor;
void main() {
    float value = perlin_noise(offsetPosition.xz / 10.0) * .5 + .5;
    fragColor = vec4(value, offsetPosition.y * 0.05 + 0.5, 0., 1.);
}
</script>

<!--script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Changing the scaling factor of my noise made it work perfectly. Thank you so much!